# How can I use SVN through a proxy?

Tags: proxy, svn

How can I use Subversion through a proxy? Currently the only way for my to connect to the internet through a proxy, so a proxy has to be specified.

Answer (score 15):

If you are using Linux, you can put this in `~/.subversion/servers` and it should work:

```
[global]
http-proxy-exceptions = *.myowndomain.com
http-proxy-host = proxyaddr.mydomain.com
http-proxy-port = 3128
http-proxy-username = userme
http-proxy-password = passyou
http-compression = no
```

On Windows, if you are using [TortoiseSVN](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tortoisesvn/), the equivalent file is `%APPDATA%\Subversion\servers`.

Comment: This trick works on Mac OSX too. http://code.swapnonil.com/2011/07/05/accessing-svn-repositories-through-proxy-on-mac-osx-and-linux/